# Compare \CurrentOption with a string

Tags: conditionals, package-options

I encountered a problem that I want to compare the `\CurrentOption` with a string.

In the `.tex` file I have a code below.

```
\usepackage[en-ver]{cufestatletter}
```

Then I want to use `\ifx` to determine whether I use `en-ver` option or not. This is the code I use now.

```
\ifx \CurrentOption \en-ver
\chead{\cufestatlogo}
\else
\lhead{\cufestatlogo}
\fi
```

I have declared the option `en-ver` using:

```
\DeclareOption{en-ver}{\def\cufestatlogo
{\hspace*{-0.6in} \includegraphics[scale=0.07]{Header_En_ver.jpg}}}
```

However, this `\ifx` code doesn't work at all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Sounds like an interesting question :) Do you think you could turn your snippets into a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) It'll really help folks who wish to look at your problem. Welcome :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to test for the option `en-ver`:

- Testing the effect that `\cufestatlogo` will be defined by the option:

  ```
  \let\cufestatlogo\relax % initialization
  \DeclareOption{en-ver}{\def\cufestatlogo{...}}
  ...
  \ifx\cufestatlogo\relax
    % option en-ver not used
  \else
    % option en-ver used
  \fi
  ```
- Adding a switch:

  ```
  \newif\ifcufestatlogo
  \DeclareOption{en-ver}{%
    \def\cufestatlogo{...}%
    \cufestatlogotrue
  }%
  ...
  \ifcufestatlogo
    % option en-ver used
  \else
    % option en-ver not used
  \fi
  ```
- LaTeX's `\@ifpackagewith{<package name>}{<option list>}{<then>}{<else>}`:

  ```
  \@ifpackagewith{cufestatletter}{en-ver}{%
    % option en-ver used
  }{%
    % option en-ver not used
  }
  ```